# Objective-C: how to compare 2 PLists

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I'm a total newbie to Objective-C and have been tasked with an assignment to compare 2 builds of same app for differences in their Info.plist and Defaults.plist.

I have been able to figure out the steps to read the PLists from app bundle but am having difficulty figuring out how to compare EVERY key in PLists to its counterpart file. For illustration if I need to compare Info.plist between 2 app bundle (lets say build_100 and build_101), how do I recursively go to each key in build_100 and compare the same key in build_101 to verify if they are same or not.

Its easy if both PLists are same because `isEqualToDictionary` will return TRUE but problem occurs if something in a nested dictionary is different between both the builds.

Going through related queries here, it clear to me that the answer is that I write a recursive method that iterates through both PLists but I'm having a real frustrating time to figure out a way to do this for a nested dictionary like `Info.plist`.

Comment: @Prateek: I had an additional answer (and a follow-up question) from another use which seems to have vanished. I'm wondering if there's something you did that caused it as, you seem to be the last user updating this question.

Comment: He didn't. You can check his changes clicking on the edit.

Comment: @Rahul: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13084002/revisions

Comment: @Sulthan, Prateek: I'm a bit new to this sites usage guidelines so ignore my silly questions :) However, I'm sure there was another comment which I had responded to and its missing now. Not sure how that happened.

Answer (score 1):

So I've finally figured this thing out so thought of sharing it with others for future reference. I'm sure there'll be some other lost soul in future looking for something similar (or at least I hope :)).

The way I wrote my code was to:

1. Read both Plists in NSDictionaries
2. Treat one Plist as "to be tested" and other as the reference (to compare against) to find out if its a Pass/Fail
3. Loop through all keys in "to be tested" Plist and compare each one of them in "reference" Plist
4. When it came to compare an Array or Dictionary, this check (that's the part I was struggling with) had to be a recursive check

The code to write for step #1, 2, 3 is straight forward so I'm going to give the method I wrote for #4 which was the crux of my original question.

This function compareSourceObject() will take 3 arguments:

- `sourceObject`: object to be tested
- `targetObject`: object to compare against
- `trailPath`: string that'll hold the entire path of the key that has failed

```
- (void)compareSourceObject:(id)sourceObject andTargetObject:(id)targetObject withBreadcrumbTrail:(NSString *)trailPath{
    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] init];

    if ([sourceObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
        for(id item in sourceObject){
            [self compareSourceObject:[sourceObject objectForKey:item] andTargetObject:[targetObject objectForKey:item] withBreadcrumbTrail:[trailPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"->%@", item]];
        }
    }
    else if ([sourceObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
        for (int counter=0; counter %d", counter]];
        }
    }
    else if(![sourceObject isEqual:targetObject]){
        NSLog(@"Values do not match. Value in \"TestedDicationary\" is (%@) but the reference dict has (%@)", targetObject, sourceObject);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Comments/Suggestions/Optimizations are more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Take one plist, and interpret the properties as a set (`NSSet`) of string values, e.g.

`:items:0:assets array`

`:items:0:assets:0:kind string VALUE`

Note I am using `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` format to describe a property - `path type [value]`.

Then do the same for the second plist and compare the sets using `NSSet` functions.

Comment: @Rahul Basically I am advising to flatten the hierarchy.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more on how to do this. I have figured out a way to do what I wanted but I'll be very interested to look at alternate ways to do the same thing.